# Create list of tables by loop in R

Tags: r, list, loops, formatting

I am struggling to create **list of tables** (object = table, not data.frame) by loop in R.
Structure of my data is also a little bit complicated - **sometimes the table function do not give 2x2 table** - **how to fill tables with incomplete dimensions to 2x2 automatically**?

Sample data (in real dataset much much larger...)

```
my.data <- data.frame(y.var = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0),
                      sex = rep(c("male","female"), times = 5),
                      apple = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
                      orange = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                      ananas = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))


#    y.var    sex apple orange ananas
# 1      0   male     0      1      0
# 2      1 female     1      0      0
# 3      0   male     1      1      1
```

Look into creating tables - for apple I have nice 2x2 tables

```
table(my.data$y.var, my.data$apple)
#     0 1
#   0 2 2
#   1 5 1        .... Ok, nice 2x2 table.
table(my.data$y.var, my.data$apple, my.data$sex)
# , ,  = female
#     0 1
#   0 1 0
#   1 3 1
# , ,  = male
#     0 1
#   0 1 2
#   1 2 0        .... Ok, nice 2x2 table.
```

However for ananas I have only 2x1 tables

```
table(my.data$y.var, my.data$ananas)
#     0                                                 #     0 1
#   0 4                                                 #   0 4 0
#   1 6        .... NOT Ok! I need 2x2 table like this: #   1 6 0
table(my.data$y.var, my.data$ananas, my.data$sex)
# , ,  = female
#     0                                                 #     0 1
#   0 1                                                 #   0 1 0
#   1 4        .... NOT Ok! I need 2x2 table like this: #   1 4 0
# , ,  = male
#     0                                                 #     0 1
#   0 3                                                 #   0 3 0
#   1 2        .... NOT Ok! I need 2x2 table like this: #   1 2 0
```

I can do list manually like this, however this is not very practical.

```
my.list <- list(table(my.data$y.var, my.data$apple),
             table(my.data$y.var, my.data$apple, my.data$sex),
             table(my.data$y.var, my.data$orange),
             table(my.data$y.var, my.data$orange, my.data$sex),
             table(my.data$y.var, my.data$ananas),
             table(my.data$y.var, my.data$ananas, my.data$sex))
```

How to do self-correcting-table-dimensions-loop? Necessary for following analyses...

Comment: Can you show your expected output.  I would say, convert to factor with levels specified before applying the `table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the list of columns after converting the columns of interest to have the same `levels` with `factor` and then do a `table` and keep the output in the `list`

```
my.data[-2] <- lapply(my.data[-2], factor, levels = 0:1)
lst1 <- lapply(my.data[3:5], function(x) table(my.data$y.var, x))
```

Comment: Yes, I will accept this as an answer! Thank you @akrun! You saved me!

Comment: @LadislavNaďo Thank you very much